# Online version of scikit-learn's TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, vectorization

I'm looking to use scikit-learn's `HashingVectorizer` because it's a great fit for online learning problems (new tokens in text are guaranteed to map to a "bucket").  Unfortunately the implementation included in scikit-learn doesn't seem to include support for tf-idf features.  Is passing the vectorizer output through a `TfidfTransformer` the only way to make online updates work with tf-idf features, or is there a more elegant solution out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intrinsically you can not use TF IDF in an online fashion, as the IDF of all past features will change with every new document - which would mean re-visiting and re-training on all the previous documents, which would no-longer be online.

There may be some approximations, but you would have to implement them yourself.

Comment: Doesn't Lucene etc. effectively do "online" TF IDF?

Comment: Not for learning a model, no. Only for doing a search which is easier and a  different problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can do "online" TF-IDF, contrary to what was said in the accepted answer.

In fact, every search engine (e.g. Lucene) does.

What does not work if assuming you have TF-IDF *vectors* in memory.

Search engines such as lucene naturally avoid keeping all data in memory. Instead they load one column at a time (which due to sparsity is not a lot). IDF arises trivially from the length of the inverted list.

The point is, you don't *transform* your data into TF-IDF, and then do standard cosine similarity.

Instead, you use the *current* IDF *weights* when computing similarities, using a *weighted cosine similarity* (often modified with additional weighting, boosting terms, penalizing terms, etc.)

This approach will work essentially with any algorithm that allows **attribute weighting at evaluation time**. Many algorithms will do, but very few implementations are flexible enough, unfortunately. Most expect you to multiply the weights into your data matrix before training, unfortunately.

Comment: That does not allow for learning in an online fashion. There is a difference between maintaining the TF-IDF values in an online fashion and learning a model with TF-IDF in an online fashion. The question is specifically for "online learning problems"

Comment: Well, you can integrate this in some learning methods. Most obviously, **kNN classification will work just fine**. Most other methods based on distances will be fine, too: the weights of a distance function change, but they could be query dependant anyway for many methods!

Comment: Only the naive case will be fine. If you use any accelerated querying structure for distance metrics like a kdtree that supports incremental building it will no longer work. 
Ultimately, the general case is you can't do it unless you develop some approximation.

Comment: The **k-d-tree can handle weights** just fine. But these won't work with high-dimensional data like text though, anyway. For sparse data like text, inverted lists are the best index, see Lucene.

Comment: No one mentioned weighted data, why are you talking about weights? kdtree will not work in an increment setting with IDF, as IDF changes the values of all previous features - making all of the kdtree wrong. 
None of what you said changes that kNN is a special case where you can do an online TF-IDF, but even then only in restricted scenarios.

Comment: I'm talking about IDF weighted attributes... use weighted *distances*, don't merge the weights into your data at load time. It will work just fine, trust me. Lucene does it. And you can do the same in many other algorithms, including kd-tree. (Try implementing support for weighted euclidean distances, it's straightforward).