# SGDClassifier with HashingVectorizer and TfidfTransformer

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I would like to understand if it is possible to train an online SGDClassifier (with partial_fit) using HashingVectorizer and TfidfTransformer. Simply joining them in a Pipeline will not work as TfidfTransformer is stateful so that would break the online learning process. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517793/online-version-of-scikit-learns-tfidfvectorizer) says it's not possible to use tf-idf in an online fashion but a comment on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931865/using-partial-fit-with-scikit-pipeline) suggests that it may somehow be possible: *"In particular if you use stateful transformers as TfidfTransformer you will need to do several passes on your data"*. Is that possible without loading the whole training set into memory? If so, how? If not, is there an alternative solution to combine HashingVectorizer with tf-idf on large datasets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is that possible without loading the whole training set into memory?

No. `TfidfTransformer` needs to have the entire `X` matrix in memory. You'll need to roll your own tf-idf estimator, use that to compute per-term document frequencies in one pass over the data, then do another pass to produce tf-idf features and fit a classifier to them.